# Firefox WebAudio accessing microphone doesn't work

Tags: firefox

I can use WebAudio to access the microphone fine under Chrome, and OS level apps can access the microphone without issue.  However, Firefox gets nothing but "dead air" when I try to access the microphone.  I have tried Googling for an answer, without success. (I have given the site(s) permission to access the necessary hardware, and I have disabled all addons, even tried a fresh profile.)

Update: I forgot to note that Firefox shows the red microphone icon in the location bar, indicating the site has access and is using the mic.  I can even get a sound file that matches the recording time, but the file itself is silent (that is, it's a valid audio file, but it has a completely "flat" wave form in Audacity).

Comment: Is the site you are using secure (https)? It's a long shot, but if not, that could be the reason, assuming you are using an old version of chrome which could work with http microphone access.

Comment: Not affected by site or http/https.

Comment: It shouldn't work locally neither... 
Driver was up to date when you installed/updated firefox? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. I'm not sure what you mean by "It shouldn't work locally neither."  It doesn't work in Firefox, period. I can get local non-browser apps to access the mic (and play back) without trouble.

Comment: Firefox will not give access to sites that run on localhost, that you render from local files, or run via http connection, without SSL. It used to, now it does not.

Comment: Even on https it doesn't work (as I mentioned above).

Comment: If Firefox inspector doesn't print any errors, I would check Windows Privacy Settings to see if Firefox have permissions for "Use your microphone". That's all I've got. Good luck!

Comment: Try the advice in the Support article [What to do if Firefox won't play any sounds](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-to-do-if-firefox-wont-play-any-sounds) (including following pertinent links).

Comment: @harrymc: Little of that (arguably none) is relevant, as playback is not an issue. I can play valid audio that Firefox did not try to create. I simply cannot access my mic in Firefox. I still tried/checked everything in that article that I hadn't already done, with no success.

Comment: Sorry to ask but When you say the file is silent, is that via playback through another piece of software

Comment: Yes. And Audacity shows a completely flat wave form.

Comment: Also is this not a programming question. Is the gain level up?

Comment: This is a user context; I'm not involved in the programming. Yes, gain is up.

Comment: Do you have microphone functionality on others sites? It could be a nuance of how the site you are accessing is coded.

Comment: In a comment above I already answered this: It doesn't matter which site it is, I get this behavior everywhere.

Comment: With the new versions of Firefox, you need to grant permission to let websites access the camera and microphone. See if this [Support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1168156) helps.

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, and my question explicitly states that I have done so. Otherwise the red microphone wouldn't be appearing, nor--presumably--would I get a "silent" audio file that matches the attempted recording time. I would get no file at all.

Comment: Could it be that you specified the wrong microphone when allowing the website?

Comment: @harrymc: I checked that, and then disabled all other potential input sources so only the mic is available.

Comment: @Heptite Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Heptite Have you tried uninstalling your microphones driver to use/install windows' standard driver?What's the name of your microphone's driver?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring The latest (54.0.1), but it's been an issue for more than one version of Firefox. I don't think the driver is the issue, since other apps (and Chrome) have no problem accessing the mic. I'll try it anyway, though.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Driver didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Heptite Is your microphone mono or stereo?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Device identifies as 1-channel, so mono.

Comment: @Heptite You could install a second firefox by using the installer and changing the installation path and then you could try it there.

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Didn't make a difference. I still get a "flat" waveform in an audio file.

Comment: @Heptite Do you have headphones plugged in while recording?On my computer the track is silent as soon as I unplug my headphones and I need to plug them in again and restart firefox to get it working.Just to be sure does it work with https://www.speakpipe.com/voice-recorder?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring It's a desktop, so I always have speakers plugged in. Speakpipe says "No sound from the microphone"

Comment: @Heptite Have you tried running firefox in safe mode?(To do so press shift while starting firefox)

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Yes, the problem persists in safe mode.

Comment: @Heptite What's currently the microphones sample rate?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring 1 channel, 16 bit, 48000 Hz

Comment: @Heptite You could try [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/nightly/all/).

Comment: @Heptite Have you tried 64 and 32 bit versions of Firefox?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring Firefox currently runs in 32 bit mode due to addons preventing 64 bit. However, when I started it on a clean profile it ran in 64 bit mode. So in effect, yes, I've tried both.

Comment: @Heptite Have you tried Nightly as I suggested above?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring I was in the process of doing that. I have now tested it, and it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @Heptite Does any program access the microphone while using Firefox (for example Cortana)?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring As far I know, no. I've done my best to disable Cortana.

Comment: @Heptite Have you tried a clean Windows boot (only Microsoft services enabled)?

Comment: @nullterminatedstring No, and I'm thinking it might not be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to use Firefox ESR 52.x version.  All newer versions are missing NPAPI Plugins which maybe required for the WebAudio you are using.

It would help if you would specify what WebAudio solution you are using.

Also one thing that came into my mind is do you have multiple microphones? (like one integrated in your notebook?)  Maybe you need to un-mute mic2 or such settings.

**EDIT-1**
Maybe it can be connected to this Firefox bug [MediaStreamAudioSourceNode cycle collection happening too soon with getUserMedia](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934512)

**EDIT-2**
I have performed multiple tests with my Firefox ESR 52.2.1 on the site: `webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html`.  It appears that Firefox is working correctly and records everything that I have tried.  I presume then that the issue is with your hardware configuration or maybe SSL certificates

First I'll ask you to share some information again:
Please run in powershell (start powershell.exe) this command (don't forget to edit out any sensitive information):
`Get-CimInstance win32_sounddevice | fl *`
Then based on manufacturer do the second query (replace the `IDT` with your own manufacturer):
`gwmi win32_systemdriver | ? caption -match 'IDT' | fl *`

Second I'll present pictures that I have collected from my computer:

The command `Get-CimInstance win32_sounddevice | fl *` produces:
[The sound devices on my computer](https://pastebin.com/RDew0M6G) .

There you can see I have USB general audio and internal IDT.  Find it on the `Manufacturer                : IDT` line

Then you have to do a query, based on the manufacturer, again from powershell 
`gwmi win32_systemdriver | ? caption -match 'IDT' | fl *`
Which should produce something like this:

[my IDT information](https://pastebin.com/NFi3wzJ3)

Next to check your sound & microphone properties (please post here pictures of your configuration):

I'll demonstrate it on my configuration (I have Windows 7 so you have to find equivalent on Windows 10) and I have only internal microphone present so I'm showing it on it:

### First microphone settings:

1. Recording devices present on my computer
   [image: Recording devices present on my computer]
2. Internal microphone levels?
   [image: Internal microphone levels?]
3. Which default microphone level is selected?
   [image: Which default microphone level is selected?]
4. Endpoint name?
   [image: Endpoint name?]

### Now for the Firefox verification:

5. Default Microphone is selected?
   [image: Default Microphone is selected?]
6. Valid certificate and connection encrypted?
   [image: Valid certificate and connection encrypted?]
7. Microphone permissions overview on the site
   [image: Microphone permissions overview on the site]
8. Finished recording from Firefox ESR 52.2.1 
   [image: When I'm recording from Firefox ESR 52.2.1]

### Last but not the least the driver version:

9.The driver version
[image: The driver version]

Comment: [Web Audio is an HTML 5 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). It is entirely unrelated to NPAPI.

Comment: @DanielB Ah, you are right, my thought was on WebAudio (via some plugin) not Web Audio API :).  Thank you for clearing this up.  Anyways my second question would be still valid

Comment: Only one mic, and it's not muted. I've made sure Firefox is accessing the correct source.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I'm reading the details of that bug wrong, it doesn't appear to be the same issue. (And the timing is wrong, too, I think.)

Comment: @Heptite: On what OS are you trying it?  Did you try it on different OS?  Does it have the same issue.  Did you try to downgrade the Firefox?

Comment: Windows 10. It's currently not feasible for me to try another OS. I have not tried downgrading.

Comment: @tukan Just tried the 52.2.1 ESR. Problem remains, unfortunately.

Comment: @Heptite: did you uninstall the newer version?  (completely even with hidden registry entries with tool like total uninstall or revo?).  Could you post your `about:support` and your `Audio Backend`?   For example mine is `wasapi`.  What kind of sound card do you have?  What version of sound card drivers do you have?  Did you try to update those?

Comment: I didn't uninstall, just installed to a secondary location and ran from there. Backend is `wasapi`. Drivers are up to date. Audio is "Intel(R) Display Audio" (not sure how to get more details than that).

Comment: @Heptite that is rather ordinary setup - is that notebook you are using?  One note on the page where you are using it, are you creating the page or is it public?  Did you try it on different page?  Is the result the same?  It may also be part of this `https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/issues/389` and perhaps this PR should fix it `https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/pull/421`

Comment: It's a PC desktop built with laptop parts (Fanless PC, using an i7 core). It's a problem on all websites that tries to use my mic. I've been using https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html for testing, though.

Comment: @Heptite: please see my newest Edit-2

Comment: @tukan A lot of information you're asking for, and I really don't want to post it all,  especially since you're essentially asking me to verify stuff I've already verified.  By the way, the "use default" in the Page Info->Permissions does not mean what you say it means. It only determines whether permissions are used, or user custom permissions.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for quite a lot of information as I have presented mine and there is nothing secret about it - only review your configuration if it is correct.  It probably is your HW or your OS settings as Firefox looks to work correctly.  About the Info-> Permissions you are right.  If you can not present all the information I'm afraid, I can not help you more.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just exhausted by troubleshooting this, and I really have verified what you want me to verify again. I spent _many_ hours on this over the period of literally weeks before I even posted my question. I cannot stress enough: The hardware works. Literally any other application (including other browsers) have no problem accessing the hardware correctly.

Comment: @Heptite: Don't worry I understand, debugging these errors can be exhausting. I think the best way would be to file a bug to bugzilla for the firefox project.  Only one thing comes to my mind to try - download some linux live-cd (slax, knoppix, opensuse livecd, etc.) and create an bootable usb drive and try to run firefox and record it from there.